# Disable authentication for an app cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

I have a server and I make a tunnel with cloudflare to be able to access from outside creating an application in **Cloudflare Zero Strust** and I am trying to disable **all the policies** so that it allows me to access the application without authentication.

[image]

But nothing works, whenever I try to enter my linkstream.domain.org application, it asks me for authentication via email.

The reason is that this application allows me to play streams so I don't want it to have authentication to access.

I've searched and configured everything, but I can't remove this authentication from cloudflare:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloudflare Access** is a product that can be used to add authentication to an application. If you want your application to be public (i.e. no authentication), I'd recommend not adding it to Access at all. You can set up a Cloudflare Tunnel without adding any Access application, for example to expose a webserver to the public.

I'd recommend looking also at the [Allow policies](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/policies/access/#allow).